# Storage for variables in cypress for reuse

Tags: cypress

Does anyone know how in cypurs, after running tests, to save variable values ​​in some storage so that when the tests are restarted, take these values ​​from there ?

for example, when a test is used to check if a password has been changed/ reset password, so that when the test is restarted, it is possible to use the new cached password

Answer (score 0):

The Cypress test runner browser is cleared between runs, so using local storage or cookies will not work.

### Persisting general data

An easy solution to persist data between instances of the test runner is by reading and writing a file to your local filesystem. You can check-in this file using version control (e.g. git) if you'd like to share it with the project.

**This method should not be used for persisting user credentials in plaintext.**

[Reading a local file with Cypress](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/readfile.html)

```
cy.readFile('path/to/my/configuration.json').as('configuration')
```

[Writing a local file with Cypress](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/writefile.html)

```
cy.writeFile('path/to/my/configuration.json', { dataKey: 'someValue' })
```